# Best practice to delete array of objects in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i have a question. I'm trying to delete array of objects and thinking that the approach i'm trying to implement could be optimized more.

Does this function sends only one query to database to delete all of the objects ?

```
 public function removeData(array $files)
 {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $this->entityManager->remove($file);
    }
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return true;
 }
```

Maybe i should use [bulk deletion](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html#bulk-deletes) ?

I need some opinions.

Thanks.

Comment: If your entities came from query, use bulk delete.... As written in the doc...

Comment: Isn't this a premature optimization?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with query builder like this :

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->delete('Foods', 'f');
$qb->where("f.name = {$pizza}");
```